# Redemption throws error when attempting to call GetDefaultFolder with rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderAllItemsSearch

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-redemption

I have what should appear to be a trivial folder request in Redemption

```
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.Logon("", "", false, true, 0, false);
var folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderAllItemsSearch);
```

upon calling this code I get the exception

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Could not retrieve special folder entry id'

if I call the same code but request rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox then it works as expected. Any ideas what this could be or what im failing to do?

Comment: What is your version of Outlook? Is this an Exchange or a PST store?

Comment: Its exchange and its outlook 2016

Comment: Is it online or a cached store?

Comment: ah yes it was in offline cached. I not sure how I had got it into that state but by brining it back online it is now working again. Thanks for your help